# Beginner Actionscript / Flash - Multiple Instances of a Symbol, Velocity

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm a Web Design student who's lightly touching on Actionscript in class and I'm having some issues with my homework. The assignment is to create 10 balloons using one symbol and make them rise to the top of the screen at different speeds and stop using only AS (no timeline animation stuff.)

I think I almost have it, but I am unsure of why I cannot alter the speeds of each balloon. They all rise together. Is there something that I'm not doing correctly?

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

var Cball:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball.x = 400;
Cball.y = 575;
addChild(Cball);



var Cball1:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball1.x = 200;
Cball1.y = 575;
addChild(Cball1);

var Cball2:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball2.x = 385;
Cball2.y = 575;
addChild(Cball2);

var Cball3:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball3.x = 500;
Cball3.y = 575;
addChild(Cball3);

var Cball4:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball4.x = 600;
Cball4.y = 575;
addChild(Cball4);

var Cball5:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball5.x = 405;
Cball5.y = 575;
addChild(Cball5);

var Cball6:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball6.x = 333;
Cball6.y = 575;
addChild(Cball6);

var Cball7:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball7.x = 250;
Cball7.y = 575;
addChild(Cball7);

var Cball8:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball8.x = 100;
Cball8.y = 575;
addChild(Cball8);

var Cball9:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball9.x = 700;
Cball9.y = 575;
addChild(Cball9);


var xVel:Number = 0;
var yVel:Number = -5;



addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop, false, 0, true);

function onLoop(evt:Event):void {


// THis is for balloon number A ********************
Cball.x += xVel;
Cball.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball.y >= 575) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number A script ******************


// THis is for balloon number 1 ********************
Cball1.x += xVel;
Cball1.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball1.y >= 575) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball1.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 1 script ******************


    // THis is for balloon number 2 ********************
Cball2.x += xVel;
Cball2.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball2.y >= 550) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball2.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 2 script ******************

    // THis is for balloon number 3 ********************
Cball3.x += xVel;
Cball3.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball3.y >= 550) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball3.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 3 script ******************

    // THis is for balloon number 4 ********************
Cball4.x += xVel;
Cball4.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball4.y >= 550) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball4.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 4 script ******************

    // THis is for balloon number 5 ********************
Cball5.x += xVel;
Cball5.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball5.y >= 550) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball5.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 5 script ******************

    // THis is for balloon number 6 ********************
Cball6.x += xVel;
Cball6.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball6.y >= 550) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball6.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 6 script ******************

    // THis is for balloon number 7 ********************
Cball7.x += xVel;
Cball7.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball7.y >= 550) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball7.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 7 script ******************

    // THis is for balloon number 8 ********************
Cball8.x += xVel;
Cball8.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball8.y >= 550) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball8.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 8 script ******************

    // THis is for balloon number 9 ********************
Cball9.x += xVel;
Cball9.y += yVel;
// Check for collisions on every frame
if (Cball9.y >= 550) {
    yVel = -5;
}// end if
if (Cball9.y <= 25) {
    yVel = 0;
} // end if
// End of balloon number 9 script ******************
} // end onloop function
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set same yVel for each ball, so the balls will rise in the same speed.

So try to set different yVel for ball.

```
var ySpeeds:Array = [-10,-9, -8, -7, -6, -5,-4,-3,-2,-1];

var save:Array = ySpeeds.concat();//save the speed

for (var i:int = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

   var ball:MovieClip = this['Cball' + i] as MovieClip;//get the target ball

   ball.x += xVel;
   ball.y += ySpeeds[i - 1];//set position

   if (ball.y >= 550) {
      ySpeeds[i - 1] = save[i - 1];//reset the speed
   } else if (ball.y <= 25) {
     ySpeeds[i - 1] = 0;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the balloon symbol you have made and bring up it's actionscript and then add this to it's first frame.

```
var yVel:Number = 0.0;
```

This next code is for your main timeline.
This code should do almost exactly what yours does, just without all the typing. Instead of creating each object pre-runtime I create them dynamically and store them in an array.(For further explanation see the bottom of this post.)

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

var xPosition:Number = 10.0;
var balloons:Array = new Array();
var numBalloons:int = 10;

for(var index:int = 0; index < numBalloons; index++) {
    var cBall:MovieClip = new rainbow();

    cBall.x = xPosition;
    cBall.y = 400; // <- [Insert Window Height Here] - [The Radius of the Movie Clip]

    cBall.yVel = (1 + (Math.random() * (10 - 1)); // Min + Math.random() * (Max - Min)
                                                  // Gives you a velocity (1 U 10)

    balloons.push(addChild(cBall)); // Your adding a new balloon to the array and
                                    // adding it to the stage at the same time

   xPosition += 10; // <- [Insert the Diameter of One Balloon here] and maybe
                              // some buffer space

}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {

    for(var index:int = 0; index < numBalloons; index++) {
        if(balloons[index].y > 0) {
            balloons[index].y += yVel; // Update each balloons y position each frame
        }
    }

}
```

I find it easier to code with classes rather than the timeline but this code should work. If you code with classes or the timeline it is still "compiled" into a '.swf'. In most cases it's much easier to dynamically create objects rather than having to create them one by one. Also in your question you say that "...make them rise to the top of the screen at **different speeds**..." but in your code they all go the same speed, so in my code I just assigned each balloon a random yVel. If you have any questions or if the code doesn't work just let me know, I'm at a lab right now without Flash though, so it might take a little while to get back to you.

Further explanation of top:

Instead of having to type the below code ten times,

```
var Cball1:MovieClip = new rainbow();
Cball1.x = 200;
Cball1.y = 575;
addChild(Cball1);
```

I just use this code

```
for(var index:int = 0; index < numBalloons; index++) {
    var cBall:MovieClip = new rainbow();

    cBall.x = xPosition;
    cBall.y = 400; // <- [Insert Window Height Here] - [The Radius of the Movie Clip]

    cBall.yVel = (1 + (Math.random() * (10 - 1)); // Min + Math.random() * (Max - Min)
                                                  // Gives you a velocity (1 U 10)

    balloons.push(addChild(cBall)); // Your adding a new balloon to the array and
                                    // adding it to the stage at the same time

   xPosition += 10; // <- [Insert the Diameter of One Balloon here] and maybe
                              // some buffer space

}
```